# java code style issues in JDK such as if ((t = table) != null)

Tags: java

I am facing an issue that confused me always while checking the source code in JDK.
Below is code snippet from ConcurrentHashMap.
Why don't to use **table** varible directly? but rather to assign it to the **t** local var. is this a recommended style in java?

```
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        if (value == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        Node<K,V>[] t;
        if ((**t** = **table**) != null) {
            Traverser<K,V> it = new Traverser<K,V>(**t**, **t**.length, 0, t.length);
            for (Node<K,V> p; (p = it.advance()) != null; ) {
                V v;
                if ((v = p.val) == value || (v != null && value.equals(v)))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: If you're running multiple threads then `table` might be changed by another thread and become null partway through the method. But `t` cannot. This is a possible way of avoiding an exception.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running multiple threads then `table` might be changed by another thread and become null partway through the method. But `t` cannot be changed elsewhere, because it only exists inside this method. This is a way of avoiding a possible exception.